# Java SimpleDateFormat cut trailing 0-digits of SSS

Tags: java, simpledateformat, trailing

hi i have an simple date format

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

It formats the date like this

```
2014-04-23 13:15:59.390
```

is it possible to remove the trailing 0, except when the digit it it is not 0?

```
2014-04-23 13:15:59.39
```

ok i've found my problem

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
```

gives me what i want, the problem is that i'm comparing it with a date-string which comes from a database.

The database reads it from a timesamp column, which contains the correct value, but i'm reading it with a

```
resultSet.getString(i)
```

and for some reason it cutts the last digit... So my question should be, why does resultSet.getString cut the last character when reading a date field?

Comment: you are right, i've rewritten my question

Comment: Have you tried a single S?

Comment: yes, but it cuts the digits completely

Comment: what if it ends in `00` - how many zeroes should be trimmed? What about `000`?

Comment: As per the java reference "Fractional seconds are handled specially: they're zero-padded on the right.", you'll have to probably convert to string and remove it manually.

Comment: use a regex to drop trailing zeros

Comment: sorry i think now my question is pointless... i first need to get sure what i really want ^^ i'll close it

Comment: do a replace for `[0]*$`

Comment: @wutzebaer Do not close your question, it can be useful to other people.

Comment: ok if you still like my question: i've continued my story =)

Comment: @wutzebaer Do not alter the essence of your Question. When you discover a new question, make a new Question posting to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String methods to trim a trailing zero:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(date).replaceAll("0$", "");
```

To trim up to 2 trailing zeroes:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(date).replaceAll("0?0$", "");
```

Comment: Does he want to trim or to preserve them?

Comment: Wouldn't that trim the zeros in the date as well?

Comment: @Bohemain i think you should know replaceAll method in which class exist

Comment: @MattK No. The `$` anchor is "end of input" - it will only match at the end

Answer (score 2):

On the resulting string, do a `replaceFirst("[0]*$", "")`

For example:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(new Date()).replaceFirst("[0]*$", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be a locale-specific issue you are getting. Try this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.ENGLISH);
```